# How to use UITextChecker to find misspelled word

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, misspelling, uitextchecker

I want to use UITextChecker to find the wrong word. Unfortunately, my code does not work as I expected. Can anyone correct my mistake, please? Here is my code. https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ib8e.png

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Add you code to description, not  an image

Answer (score 1):

your code working properly

```
func isCorrect(word:String)->Bool{
    let checker = UITextChecker()
    let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: word.utf16.count)
    let mispelledRange = checker.rangeOfMisspelledWord(in: word, range: range, startingAt: 0, wrap: false, language: "en")

    return mispelledRange.location == NSNotFound
}

print(isCorrect(word: "apple"))
print(isCorrect(word: "ppale"))
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason it works for me in a playground but returns true for everything in my app

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-check-a-string-is-spelled-correctly-using-uitextchecker) you can find the example for `UITextChecker`

Consider the example below:

```
func isReal(word: String) -> Bool {
    let checker = UITextChecker()
    let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: word.utf16.count)
    let misspelledRange = checker.rangeOfMisspelledWord(in: word, range: range, startingAt: 0, wrap: false, language: "en")

    return misspelledRange.location == NSNotFound
}

isReal(word: "apple") //true
isReal(word: "pple")  //false
```

Comment: I ran the code you mentioned above but it does not work like you. I think this error is due to my Xcode version. My current version is Version 11.4 beta (11N111s). Thanks bro.